# Deploy simple Jax-RS example in JBoss community AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I'm trying to deploy a simple REST example in JBOSS AS 7 but seems that I'm doing something wrong and I'm now clueless. I'm using Eclipse plugin to deploy.

The class I wrote is the following

```
@Path("/resources")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class ReceivedImagePersister {

    @POST
    @Path("/image")
    public Response save(String entry) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

}
```

Then I create a web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>API</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And a jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>api</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

When I deploy the application and try to send some data to the RESTful servlet the response is always:

(Could not find resource for relative : /image of full path: http://localhost:8080/api/resources/image)

Do I have to make some changes in configuration?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your web.xml your url pattern should /* i.e.

```
<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
```

should be

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

What i am getting at is you need let javax.ws.rs.core.Application parse your url starting from http://localhost/api/ only then will it able to detect that there is a resource named "resources" which has method "image"

Right now it is trying to lookup a resource named "image" which is under the context path /api/resources/

The following url may work for the way its been setup now
http://localhost:8080/api/resources/resources/image

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with JBoss but you should probably use a Servlet 3.0 web.xml instead of a 2.4 if you want the best compatibility with the Java EE 6 deployment model.

Answer (score 0):

The correct url for accessing what you have declared is:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/resources/resources/image
```

The first resources is the servlet mapping, and the second is the name of the rest controller.